# first draft for a logo design

Tags: logo

I hired a graphic designer to design a logo 12 days ago.  there was a maximum of 10 hours a week.
To date I have received no 1st draft and I am concerned that the first 20 hours will cost me heaps without seeing a first draft.

Am I expecting too much?

Comment: I'd do between 40 to 180 hours of research of a market's past, present and future before even beginning a first draft, so you're fine. Relax.

Comment: @Confused I would think that number is based *a lot* on who your client it. Mom and pop shops don't need that type of research done about them...

Comment: Sure... if you believe that, that's fine. But I think they deserve it. Perhaps more so than any corporate customer because they're a Mom and Pop shop. If Monsanto asked me to do a logo I probably wouldn't need do any research - just copy the skull and crossbones flag. Done!

Answer (score 3):

This depends on your contract. We can not know what the particular circumstances of your commission is. In ideal circumstances you'd look up your contract for  a project proposal. However, we do not know what kind of deal you made.*

A contract in, many ways, is just simply about enumerating operating practice so that both you as a client know what the operating procedure is. A contract is a win-win situation you should have one it saves you from a lot headaches.

In this contract you should include some a project time estimate and deadlines. **Deadlines** both for the **designer and** you as a **client****, is important otherwise nothing gets done. In general the contract should include:

- Overview and objectives of project.
- Process and milestones, aka. how do we work and when we deliver what. More importantly when it is considered done.
- Fees and expenses, how are they handled.
- A work schedule.
- And finally a Billing schedule.
- Job deliverables and intellectual property releases.
- General terms of services.

So ideally you would look at what your contract stipulates to clarify. If you did commission work without a contract with all these things and more, you have problems.

* This kind of experience is often a result of not writing down a proper contract. This could happen for many reasons such as trying to get a bargain on the project cost.

** Yes, clients with no previous knowledge of buying consultancy and services often sabotage their own projects by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

That kind of project could instead a per hour, be an overall cost of the project, for example 3 options and start building from there choosing one.

You need to put some effort and be clear on what you like and what you do not, but also be open minded if the designer good one.

12 days for one draft, depending on the result could be a little too much, but I do not know the terms.

A logo design it is not something that should be "cooked" by time, but as solid steps.

- A general Idea (from several options)
- A simplification of that idea
- A style for the logo
- Colors, font.

This is just my opinion. At the end the designer you should talk with is the one you hired.